# Systematically compare keywords using Google Trends

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, gtrendsr

Is there a way to automatically get Google Trends comparison of two keywords?
I am able to downlaod relative interest for specific keywords and locations by using the `gtrendsR` R package. However, I would like to systematically compare two keywords.

This is important because of the two-step normalization procedure that Google applies to its relative interest index.
The picture below shows what I am aming at.

[image: e]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download data normally on R with google trends, your keywords should be normalized together